# Is there an opposite function to ajaxComplete in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm wonder if there is a function in jQuery, which is the opposite of **ajaxComplete** ? I want to fire it before the ajax event, like : **beforeSend**

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
        domain = document.domain;
        if ( settings.url === "my url" ) {
            afisare_total(); 
        }
});
```

Comment: another question: Is there way to pass a variable or array from ajaxSend to ajaxComplete ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `ajaxSend()`. This will be triggered when an Ajax request is about to be sent.

Which you can use like this:

```
$( document ).ajaxSend(function() {
    $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxSend handler." );
});
```

[Which is an example taken from the JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/)

Comment: and this function fire before all ajax event ?

Comment: Quoted from the page I linked: `"Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery triggers the ajaxSend event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxSend() method are executed at this time."`

Comment: thx, man, one more question: another question: Is there way to pass a variable or array from ajaxSend to ajaxComplete ?

Comment: [Based on this](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/uniquely-identifying-ajax-requests-responses) you may be able to add a property to the request object that will later be available, [something like this seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/js1b1zf3/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the name is [ajaxSend](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/).

You can see all the events [here](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean ajaxError or ajaxSend? See [here](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) for a list of ajax events